# Basic ImageMagic disconnect: converting plain ASCII.txt file into image file ASCII.jpg - ending up with errors

Tags: imagemagick-convert

I have been trying to convert a plain text file (containing ASCII sentences / lines) into an JPEG image - not caring about any formats or styles - just a first try - keen on quick results:

After half a day trials and errors in all variations - all failing with the below (or similar) errors - and nearly going mad I have solved the following error message :

```
...
convert-im6.q16: not authorized `@a.txt' @ error/property.c/InterpretImageProperties/3516.
```

I have gotten the wanted result when I have deactivitated

```
    /etc/ImageMagick-6/policy.xml
```

into

```
 /etc/ImageMagick-6/_policy.xml
```

Can somebody explain - please - what the magic behind is with this (deactivated) file ???
And please - being sure this file should become  re-activated as it is by default - what do I need to change instead (in the file ???)

Thanks in advance with BR

Comment: What was your command? Your should just edit the policy.xml file to give permission for what you want to do. But if this is a shared server, you will need to have the hosting provided make any changes to relax permissions. You can only make them tighter.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not on a shared server, you can edit your ImageMagick  policy.xml file to give read|write permissions for the use of "@".

*I suspect the defaults are still "none" for the use of "@" even if you disable the policy.xml file*.

Then you can read a text file (in this case ipsum_lorem.txt) :

```
convert -size 1000x -font arial -pointsize 28 caption:"@ipsum_lorem.txt" x.jpg

or

cat ipsum_lorem.txt | convert -size 1000x -font arial -pointsize 28 caption:"@-" x.jpg
```

and the result should be:

[image]

Comment: I strongly assume, this is the relevant line: <policy domain="path" rights="none" pattern="@*"/> ?! What do I need to change, please ? ... rights="xxxxxxxx" ... ?

Comment: rights="read|write" and uncomment the line as well

Comment: Is this your own computer or on a shared server. With the latter, you will not be able to do that. The owner (hosting provider) will need to permit that.

Comment: Thanks for you answers to all. What are the security concerns ? This is not clear to me ...! I am just transforming ASCII-Information into  pixels within an image. What is the danger?

Comment: Someone injecting code via text onto your computer. ImageMagick has a policy.xml file to guard against all kinds of security issues. You have to relax those you do not want from the default settings which are rather tight to start.